# Returning MySql object with each row as array

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I want to query my DB and get back an array of arrays. I'm getting all my rows merged into a flat array which makes parsing through it for my purposes very hard.

php:

```
function conn($sQuery){
    $sMessage = '';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db') or die('unable to connect!');
    if($db->connect_errno){
        $message = $db->connect_error;
    } else{
        if($db->query($sQuery)){
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sQuery);
            $stmt->execute();
            $oResult = $stmt->get_result();
            while($rows = $oResult->fetch_assoc()){
                foreach($rows As $value){
                    $aRows[] = $value;
                }
            }
            $oResult->free();
            $db->close();
            return $aRows;
        } else{
            $sMessage = $db->error;
            $db->close();
            return $sMessage;
        }
    }
}

function requestNote(){
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `sender_Id` = '" . $_SESSION['user_Id'] . "'";
    $oResult = conn($sQuery);
    if(!is_array($oResult)||!isset($oResult)||empty($oResult)||is_null($oResult)){
        echo null;
    } else{
        echo json_encode($oResult);
    }
}
```

js:

```
request.done(function(oResult){
    var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(oResult);
    console.log("Json returned: ", jsonResult);
});
```

This prints:

Json returned:

```
[1, 100000, 100000, "This is a test note inserted directly into DB", "2014-10-22 15:34:15", 2, 100000, 100000, "This is the second test ...serted directly into DB", "2014-10-22 21:56:50"]
```

What I want is:

Json returned:

```
[

   [1, 100000, 100000, "This is a test note inserted directly into DB", "2014-10-22 15:34:15"], 

   [2, 100000, 100000, "This is the second test ...serted directly into DB", "2014-10-22 21:56:50"]

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while($rows = $oResult->fetch_assoc()){
     foreach($rows As $value){
         $aRows[] = $value;
     }
}
```

with

```
while($rows = $oResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     $aRows[] = $rows;
}
```

`fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` will return a simple array instead of the associative, so that your json data will not have objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `foreach` loop inside the `while` loop. The `while` iterates over the rows, so the `foreach` is then iterating over columns. It should just be:

```
        while($rows = $oResult->fetch_assoc()){
            $aRows[] = $rows;
        }
```